# Source for Yubikey AAGUID Metadata?

Tags: yubico

I'm looking for a reliable machine-readable source for Yubikey AAGUID values. The most likely-looking source I see is the [Yubikey Attestation Metadata](https://developers.yubico.com/U2F/yubico-metadata.json), however this seems to be very incomplete. A far more comprehensive list in table form is available at [Yubikey Hardware FIDO2 AAGUIDs](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016648959-YubiKey-Hardware-FIDO2-AAGUIDs), but it's embedded in a blog post, so (a) it would have to be scraped, and (b) is unlikely to be kept current over time. Is there a reliable URI that I can use to download what will always be the most current/complete metadata?

Thanks!